# Prove that a map is defined properly

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ a group and let $A,B$ subgroups of $G$. Let a map $f:A/A\cap B\to G/B$ by $(A\cap B)a\mapsto Ba$. Prove that $f$ is well defined (not depends on representitives).

I know that I need to prove that if $(A\cap B)a=(A\cap B)a'$ then $Ba=Ba'$. I don't understand why I can't argue that if $(A\cap B)a=(A\cap B)a'$ then $f((A\cap B)a)=f((A\cap B)a')$ and thus $Ba=Ba'$.

I have another solution that I don't understand why is true and the previous one doesn't:

Let $(A\cap B)a=(A\cap B)a'$. Then $a-a'\in A\cap B$. Thus $a-a'\in B$, thus $aB=a'B$.

Comment: What you have to *prove* is that if $(A\cap B)a = (A\cap B)a'$, then $Ba=Ba'$.

Comment: I think it is not right to assume $f((A \cap B)a) = f((A\cap B)a')$, you are required to prove this!! THis would in turn imply that $Ba =Ba'$.

Comment: @MPW Is it right to say that any proof that implies $Ba=Ba'$ is good in this case if and only if I show this without using $f$?

Comment: As Rick says, assuming that the application of $f$ preserves the equality $(A\cap B)a=(A\cap B)a'$ is exactly what you need to prove.

Comment: You can’t use $f$ to prove it, because what you are trying to verify is that $f$ actually *is* a function, and not something that gives you different answers depending on what you call the input. Your argument would be like saying the following: “R and B are the same letter. To verify this, define a function $f$ from the set of people to the set of letters, by taking each person to the first letter of their name. My friend Robert is also called Bob. Since $f(\text{Robert}) = \text{R}$, and $f(\text{Bob})=\text{B}$, and Robert and Bob are the same, then R=B.” Clearly wrong, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, one can't argue that

$(A \cap B)a_1 = (A \cap B)a_2 \Longrightarrow Ba_1 = f((A \cap B)a_1) = f((A \cap B)a_2) = Ba_2, \tag 1$

since $f$ is defined in terms of whatever $b$ occurs in the *exact* expression $A \cap B)b$; such a definition, on the face of it and without further analysis,  yields a $b$-dependent $f$, not a *coset*-dependent $f$; one needs to show that if, as *sets*,

$(A \cap B)a_1 = (A \cap B)a_2, \tag 2$

then

$Ba_1 = Ba_2, \tag 3$

again as *sets*; that is, $f$ depends only on the the coset $(A \cap B)b$, not on it's particular represetative $b$.

To properly prove the desired assertion, it helps to realize that, for a
any subgroup $C$ of any group $G$,

$Cg_1 = Cg_2, \; g_1, g_2 \in G \Longleftrightarrow g_2 g_1^{-1} \in C; \tag 4$

for if

$Cg_1 = Cg_2, \tag 5$

and $e \in G$ denotes the identity element, then since $e \in C$ (because $C$ is a subgroup of $G$),

$\exists c \in C, \; cg_1 = eg_2 = g_2 \Longrightarrow g_2g_1^{-1} = c \in C; \tag 6$

likewise,

$g_2g_1^{-1} \in C \Longrightarrow g_2g_1^{-1} = c \in C \Longrightarrow g_2 = cg_1 \Longrightarrow Cg_2 = C(cg_1) = (Cc)g_1 = Cg_1, \tag 7$

since

$c \in C \Longrightarrow Cc = C. \tag 8$

If this notion is applied to the present problem, we may argue that

$(A \cap B)a_1 = (A \cap B)a_2 \Longrightarrow a_2a_1^{-1} \in A \cap B \Longrightarrow a_2 a_1^{-1} \in B \Longrightarrow Ba_1 = Ba_2, \tag 8$

and we see the mapping

$(A \cap B)b \mapsto Bb \tag 9$

depends only on the coset $(A \cap B)b$ and not its particular representative $b$; thus $f$ is, in fact, well-defined.